# split multiple delimiters insert to dataframe python

Tags: python

I have a two delimiters in a file , i have to split by | and split by , and insert to 3 columns in a dataframe

```
input.txt

a,1|b,2,4|c,3
a,2|b|c,5


output should be 

a,b,c
1,[2,4],3
2,NULL,5

I have tried below but got stuck 



import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import re


file1 = open("sample.txt")

dit={}

for line in file1.readlines():
    read = re.split('\|',line.strip())
    for word in read:
        key = word.split(',')
        if(len(key) > 1):
            dit[key[0]]=key[1]
        else:
            dit[key[0]]="NULL"
        
       
df = pd.DataFrame(dit,columns=["a","b","c"],index=[0])


output 

a   b   c
2   NULL    5
```

output not updating first row & not dynamic wrt to more comma separated.

Answer (score 0):

Making a data frame from a dict requires that each dict value contain a list of the values for that column.  You overwrite previous values with the new ones, so you get only the last row in your data frame.  Instead, you have to append the values to each key's entry.

```
for word in read:
    key = word.split(',')
    if(len(key) > 1):
        dit[key[0]].append(key[1])
    else:
        dit[key[0]].append("NULL")
```

This means that you also have to initialize each entry to an empty list, so alter this processing:

```
for word in read:
    key = word.split(',')
    key_char = key[0]
    if key_char not in dit:
        dit[key_char] = []
    if(len(key) > 1):
        dit[key_char].append(key[1])
    else:
        dit[key_char].append("NULL")
```

You should then extend this for longer keys and longer values; your current code accepts only single-char keys and values.